# Can the Wasabi card and a Nigiri card be played together at once?

Tags: sushi-go

If I use a chopsticks card to play two cards, can a Wasabi I play simultaneously with a Nigiri be used together to triple the Nigiri points? My inclination from a strict reading of the rules is to think no, but from a sushi eating perspective, it seems reasonable to be able to.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The designer of the game clarified this rule in a [boardgamegeek thread](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1014756/chopsticks-wasabi-and-nigiri)

> The intention of the rule is that you can choose the order you play the two cards when using chopsticks. So you can play a Wasabi and then a Nigiri on top of it right away!